# How to force creating a new EC2 instance rather than updating an existing one in terraform?

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a terraform template, which (among other things) has a resource of type `aws_instance`. I have an existing instance that corresponds to this template, but I want to spin up a second instance, with a slightly different name.

When I execute

```
tf plan -target aws_instance.classification_server -out plan
```

terraform thinks that I want to change the name of the existing instance.

How do I tell terraform to spin up a new instance rather than update the old instance?

Comment: Simply add another instance to the terraform configuration. If you use terraform, you have to embrace its approach (which is very good). Think about it. If what you want to obtain worked, it would mean that terraform would not be able to destroy both instances...

Comment: Or use a different state file.

Answer (score 0):

To rif on @ydaetskoR answer, I copied my directory where I had my terraform project so ended up with three directories for three different instances.  Then I can change to each directory and delete or change just the instance I want. It works, but is also rather silly. There has to be a better way.

/--

---/tf1 <- for the first instance

---/tf2 <- for the second instance

---/tf3 <- for the third instance